# Menu wraps - how to control # of items

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm adding a page to a site (with BeTheme), and it's going under a new menu item.  Now the menu is wrapping to a new line for this single item.  If I move the menu item, the menu still wraps. There were 7 items, I'm adding an 8th.

Looking at the code generated, a class of "last" is being added, and that seems to control the wrapping.

There's plenty of room for the item, the wrapping seems arbitrary. I can't see where this attribute is set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shoudn't you share the nav code ?

Comment: @ArmanH I would but it's all generated by BeTheme/Wordpress.  As it happens, today the layout works fine.  I think there was some caching that interfered with the new menu.

I'll be deleting this question.